# Getting started with AWS IoT publication from device

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I'm new to AWS IoT, so it's easily possible that I've simply missed the documentation I need. For the life of me, though, I can't find anything that helps.

The problem I'm trying to solve is about as simple as it gets: from a Raspberry pi, already registered as a Thing in AWS-IoT, publish some data in a nodejs function. That's it. For now, I'm just trying to do this using certs that I've already generated for that particular Thing; eventually I want to use the API calls to actually create the corresponding Thing object and create and download its certs. That's for later, though. I figure if I can get the plain-vanilla publish scenario to work, I can do the other parts next.

There is a new api for nodejs, https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2. Most of the tutorials etc. that I've found pertain to the old api, which is completely different from the new one. Is there anything that explains, step by step, how to accomplish this simple task using the new api?

Comment: I have reverted to the older version of the API. That version works fine, and it has enough documentation and examples that it's pretty easy to get things going. I'll update to v2 if its documentation improves.